# Why is the non-type partial specialization tuple not taken?

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17, type-traits

I am attempting to achieve the following (using C++17 features):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<auto value_>
using constant_t = std::integral_constant<decltype(value_), value_>;

template<typename ... > class Tuple {};

template<auto ... values_>
class Tuple<constant_t<values_> ... > {};

int main(void)
{
    Tuple<int, int, char> types;
    Tuple<1, 2, 3> values;
}
```

Which gives me the following error in g++-7.1.0

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:15:18: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class ...> class Tuple’
     Tuple<1, 2, 3> values;
              ^
main.cpp:15:18: note:   expected a type, got ‘1’
main.cpp:15:18: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class ...> class Tuple’
main.cpp:15:18: note:   expected a type, got ‘2’
main.cpp:15:18: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class ...> class Tuple’
main.cpp:15:18: note:   expected a type, got ‘3’
```

Can anyone explain why the partial specialization does not activate for the `Tuple<1, 2, 3>`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1, 2 and 3 are not types. Your specialization doesn't (and can't) change the primary template to accept values, so you can't magically pass values where types were expected before.

If you want a template that accepts values, an alias template can do that instead of the specialization:

```
template<auto... values_>
using VTuple = Tuple<constant_t<values_>... >;
```

But it is a *separate* template.

Comment: that's what I have been trying to avoid (the alias)

Comment: but thankyou, do you have an explanation as to why the primary template can't be changed to accept values?

Comment: @FletcherBlight - By the very nature of specialization. A value is not a more specialized form of a type. It just *has* a type. The fact it has a type does't allow to substitute it for a type.